# Yeoman testing times out anywhere but locally

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, yeoman, mocha-phantomjs

I have some testing with the following structure:

```
describe('yeoman:subyeoman', function () {
   before(function (done) {
       helpers.run(path)
           .inTmpDir(function (dir) {
               ** some file copying **
           })
           .withOptions({
               'option': options
           })
           .withArguments(argumentsJson)
           .on('ready', function (generator) {
               generator.conflicter.force = true;

               var html = "some html";
               var dir = generator.destinationPath('app');
               var file = generator.destinationPath('app/file.html');

               if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) fs.mkDir(dir);
               fs.writeFile(file, html);
           })
           .on('end', function () {
               fse.removeSync(somePath);
               done();
           });
   });

   it('.....');
});
```

The `on('ready')` piece does its work both locally and inside the docker container, but inside the container never calls `generator.run()` and throws the following error:

```
Error: timeout of 20000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I've tried changing the timeout and doing it the async way but the output its still the same.

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen if you have an error in your code that doesn't bubble up with testing.  Check any manipulation to the `this` context especially.